# Unexpected behaviour of watch command

Tags: linux, command, watch

The following command which I want to use to monitor the number of files in a directory does not show the required value dynamically.

```
watch "echo \`ls -l| wc -l\`"
```

However following command works well.

```
watch "ls -l| wc -l"
```

What is the explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

It's because the shell expands backticks before `watch` is ever executed.  If you use `set -x`, you'll see that the command that actually ends up calling

```
watch "echo 42"
```

which explains why it's always the same.

You can escape the `` ` `` with a backslash to pass it literally:

```
watch "echo \`ls -l | wc -l\`"
```

Or more easily by using single quotes, which inhibit all expansions:

```
watch 'echo `ls -l | wc -l`'
```